# How to get dBc level of Cross Polarization and Sidelobe of an antenna?

Tags: antenna

I literally wonder how to convert from dB to dBc or how to get dBc level of those I mentioned in the title. Specification in [this link](https://teldatasystem.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/8203-1.pdf)

Comment: dBc = decibel relative to carrier power. There's no relation to "cross polarization" to be made, or any properties of an antenna. That's like asking "how do I convert meters to sound pressure"; these aren't describing anything related.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi Marcus, hope you're doing well. In a spec text I ran into this "Sidelobe Level: -25 dBc minimum". I tryna figüre out If I design an antenna in that I can get its side lobe level in dB. However what I wonder how to point it out in dBc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh I got a equation to get it in Wiki which requires noise signal power.

Comment: I don't know where that spec text is from, but I really only know dBc for a relation to carrier power. And that makes no sense for an antenna, because there's **no carrier** power involved, so *there is no conversion*, and we *can offer no conversion formula*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller here it's. [link](https://teldatasystem.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/8203-1.pdf)

Comment: Given that it's sidelobe, the context is obviously dB(sidelobe/mainlobe). The same goes for cross polar, the dB refers to the ratio cross_polar/main_polarisation

Comment: @BurakAktas that is a **system** spec, not an antenna spec. That's a single-carrier radar system, so there's a carrier in that... didn't you think that might have been relevant to consider?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought it meant the transmission line by "carrier"